# PHP Form- Is it possible make multiple input field insert in same table_name

Tags: php, forms

Is it possible make multiple input field insert in same table_name.

My database design

[image]

Php form
age form have five input field

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
input1          
<input type="text" name="age[]">
input2
<input type="text" name="age[]">
input3
<input type="text" name="age[]">
input4
<input type="text" name="age[]">
input5
<input type="text" name="age[]">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Php script

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into AGEGroup (AGE) values ('$_POST['age']')");
            $statement->execute();
            echo "Added Successfully.";
?>
```

It just added one record.
how to doing 5 records can all insert in database???

Thank you very much

or use for loop???

```
<?php
for($i=0, i<$_Post['age'][i],i++){
$statement = $pdo->prepare("insert into AGEGroup (AGE) values ('$_POST['age'][i]')");
            $statement->execute();
}
            echo "Added Successfully.";

?>
```

Comment: `$_Post` < you should have gotten an undefined index about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the query remains the same for all the [x] inserts you should do the prepare outside the loop, so its done only once (saves unnecessary round trips to the server)

Your prepare should also use a parameter rather than concatenate the value directly into the query, to avoid [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into AGEGroup (AGE) values (:age)");

foreach ($_POST['age'] as $age) {
    $stmt->execute([':age'=>$age]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While it it possible it is not the best to open connection on each iteration of the forloop.

I would concatenate the whole string and send the query only once.

```
$query = "";
    for($i = 0, $i < $_Post['age'][$i], $i++{
            $query .= "INSERT INTO AGEGroup (AGE) VALUES ('{$_POST['age'][$i]}');"
        }
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
```

Pay attention to $ signs before variable names, in PHP it is marking the upcoming variables for the interpreter.

Comment: PDO will not run multiple queries via a single execute

Comment: This is also open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)